# (another) LEFT JOIN issue with ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I want summary data from my 'Data' table for all companies in 'Companies' table including blank rows where there is no record in Data.

If I summarise the data in a nested SELECT clause (or in a stored query i get nothing from the data table.  For example

This is the sub select

```
SELECT    transco,
          sum(m1) AS Jan15,
FROM data
WHERE (QVmeasure = 'Vol') 
GROUP BY QVmeasure, transco
```

which outputs:

```
transco Jan15
0292    154373665
1419    134915098
```

If I use it in a sub select as follows

```
SELECT  c.SAP_Code, 
        Jan15
FROM Companies AS c
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT transco,
              sum(m1) as Jan15
       FROM data
       WHERE (QVmeasure = 'Vol') 
       GROUP BY QVmeasure, transco)
AS d
ON c.SAP_Code = d.transco
```

I get:

```
SAP_Code    Jan15
0292    
1419
```

I can get the correct result via a temporary table:

```
SELECT sum(m1) as Jan15,
    transco
INTO Temp_Table
    FROM data
    WHERE (QVmeasure = 'Vol') 
    GROUP BY QVmeasure, transco
```

followed by

```
Select c.SAP_code, 
       jan15
FROM companies AS c
LEFT JOIN Temp_Table as i
ON (c.SAP_Code = i.transco)
```

giving:

```
SAP_code    jan15
0292    154373665
1419    134915098
1423
```

but if I use temporary tables I will have to create macros and i want users to be able to run just a query.

The following works for this simple case but I can't apply it in other circumstances:

```
SELECT  c.SAP_Code,
        sum(m1) AS Jan15
FROM Companies AS c
LEFT JOIN data as d
ON c.SAP_Code = d.transco
WHERE (d.QVmeasure = 'Vol') OR (d.QVmeasure is null)
GROUP BY d.QVmeasure,c.sap_code
```

Is there something wrong with my sub select syntax or is it ACCESS (2013)

TIA

Comment: `QVmeasure` shouldn't be in the `GROUP BY` clause, since it is only used in the WHERE clause. But that is hardly the problem. This *should* work IMO. --- If you haven't solved it by now, can you upload a sample database with just the two tables (containing a few sample records) to a file hoster?

Answer (score 0):

You could nest the sub-query like this:

```
SELECT  c.SAP_Code, 
    (SELECT sum(d.m1)
    FROM data AS d
    WHERE d.QVmeasure = 'Vol' AND c.SAP_Code = d.transco
    ) AS [Jan15]
FROM Companies AS c
```